# Get value from pointer

Tags: pointers, go

I'm using a github sdk for Go. The github sdk return a struct object like:

```
type IssuesSearchResult struct {
    Total             *int    `json:"total_count,omitempty"`
    IncompleteResults *bool   `json:"incomplete_results,omitempty"`
    Issues            []Issue `json:"items,omitempty"`
}
```

If I want to print the total number like

```
result := client.Search.Issues.....
fmt.prinln(result.Total)
```

it will print the address in memory like `0xc420228080` but I want the real value like 4 or 5 , I tried to find how can I do that but I couldn't get the correct answer

Comment: Deref pointers with *. _Please_ take the Tour of Go. Now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`fmt.prinln(*result.Total)`